# Onclick event not always working

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm using onlick to call a function with different parameters but it's not always working. I'm trying to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function PopupCenterDual(url, title, w, h) {

        var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
        var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

        width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
        height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

        var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
        var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
        var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);


        if (window.focus) {
            newWindow.focus();
        }
    }

  });
```

```html
<?php if(something...) { ?>
                <button type="button" onclick="PopupCenterDual('<?php echo URL::base()?>someurl','title1','800','420'); " href="" >Register</button>

        <?php } else { ?>
        <button  type="button" onclick="PopupCenterDual('<?php echo URL::base()?>anotherurl','title2','800','420'); " href="" >Register</button>

        <?php } ?>
```

How to do that when page is fully loaded and pass these parameters?

Comment: Please check your html is not breaking.It can be happen when doing concatenation.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: PopupCenterDual is not defined... Please add your function outside (document).ready(function() {

Comment: Thank you, I did it and it's fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you define any variable or function inside any other function, You are making it accessible only from within that function scope. It's called a **local scope** variable or function. In your case you have put your function `PopupCenterDual` inside this closure function which became a local function to this function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Your local scope function 
 });
 //Move your function here to give it a global scope
```

But your onclick event is calling this function from a global scope. So, You need to move that outside it to make it global so that your onclick event handler can access it.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

Please add the function outside `(document).ready(function() {`

```
(document).ready(function() {


  });

function PopupCenterDual(url, title, w, h) {

            var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
            var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

            width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
            height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

            var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
            var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
            var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);


            if (window.focus) {
                newWindow.focus();
            }
        }
```